# Submit a form only once with JSAngular? Clicked multiple times

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way for me to have an end-user only submit a form once to a database even if he/she clicks it multiple times? I'm using Angular to process my submissions, I've tried some methods but they remove my POST and GET methods, anyone have any ideas to put me in the right direction?

```
             },
              controller: function ($scope, $modalInstance) {

                  $scope.close = function () {
                      $modalInstance.close();
                  };

                  $scope.submitFeedback = function () {

                          $scope.feedback = {
                          FeedbackRating: $scope.score,
                          FeedbackSubject: $scope.subject,
                          FeedbackUpload: 'upload',
                          FeedbackDescription: $scope.description
                      };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I do is:

```
$rootScope.isLoading = function () {
    return $http.pendingRequests.length > 0;
}
```

and on your html:

```
<button type="submit" ng-disabled="isLoading()">
```

Basically, what's happening here is that your button gets disabled as soon as your request is made.

Make sure to add $http as a dependency in your controller.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Where exactly should I be putting this? Should I be replacing anything? I apologize for asking, but it's just so I can learn how to do it next time.

Comment: if you have a parent controller, I suggest you put function in there!

Comment: Good, that's what I did! This code is on my parent controller, I'll fit it in. :)